# jQuery conditional on the url hash

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery how can I check if a user is visiting a particular direct `id` link url?

For example:

http://mydomain.com/#foo

I this case, I like to check for `foo`.

Would love something like:

```
if(jQuery.urlHasHash("foo")) {
    //logic here
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for jQuery, your browser gives you all you need with `document.location.hash`

If you want to check if such an ID exists on your page:

```
var hash = document.location.hash.replace(/^#/, '');

if (document.location.hash != '' && document.getElementById(hash) { 
  // or just: $(document.location.hash)
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/7QceB/

This might fit your needs `:)`

**Code**

```
$(function(){
    //var href = location.href; // get the url
    var href = "http://mydomain.com/#foo"; // example url
    var split = href.split("#"); // split the string; usually there'll be only one # in an url so there'll be only two parts after the splitting
    var afterSplit = "Error parsing url";
    if(split[1] != null){
        afterSplit = split[1];
    }
    // If everything went well shows split[1], if not then de default error message is shown
    alert(afterSplit);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my jsFiddle : <kbd>[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kUzfS/)</kbd>

```
// it might be from browser & / anywhere else
var url = "http://mydomain.com/#foo";
url = url.split('#').pop().split('?').pop();
var page = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
console.log(page); // foo
```

or just

```
var url = "http://mydomain.com/#foo";
var page = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); // #foo
```

After you can use if statement to know `if (page == "foo")`